# Whisper App Not Working in Various Android Emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, bluestacks

I have tried to get the app, [Whisper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sh.whisper&hl=en_US), to work in various android emulators from the Android AVD to Bluestacks to Memu and various other android emulators but to no avail.

It appears, though, for some odd reason while the app can be successfully installed and opened via these emulators,  certain features/functionality will not work as expected.

In particular making a post, responding to a post, or engaging in a conversation/chat with another user does not go through successfully. It will lead the user to believe that a message/post/response has been sent/posted, as you can see it on your end. But when verifying it by using an actual (i.e. physical) smartphone device (whether it be Android or iOS) that is also running Whisper, it's clear that it did not go through.

I'm curious A) How are the developers managing to recognize/detect the app is being run in an emulator? B) More importantly, how can I cloak or ensure that the app cannot detect its being run in an emulator and that it believes it is on a physical device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that detects if the device is an emulator. And yes I think whisper detects this and restricts emulators to use those features.

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
   return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith(MessengerShareContentUtility.TEMPLATE_GENERIC_TYPE) || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown") || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk") || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator") || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86") || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion") || (Build.BRAND.startsWith(MessengerShareContentUtility.TEMPLATE_GENERIC_TYPE) && Build.DEVICE.startsWith(MessengerShareContentUtility.TEMPLATE_GENERIC_TYPE)) || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

And to answer the second question I'm not really sure as to how you will be able to make the emulator work as a real device. But what you can do is probably modify the app itself to work on the emulator perhaps.